# Strange behaviour of FireBase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase

So, I have an HTML/CSS/JS website.

All works fine, I can upload images to FireBase storage, use it, etc.

But I have a problem, with video upload...

***video_upload.html:***

```html
...
<div>
     <p>Upload Video</p>
     <input id="fileVideo" accept="video/*" type="file" />
</div>
...
```

***video_upload.js:***

```js
async function saveChanges() {
    const video = document.getElementById('fileVideo').files[0];
    if (video != undefined) {
        await addVideoToStorage(videoID, video);
    }

    alert('Saved')
    window.location.replace("profile.html");
}

saveButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    saveChanges();
});
```

***video_upload_to_storage.js:***

```js
async function addVideoToStorage(videoID, file) {
    const storage = getStorage(app);
    const storageRef = ref(storage, `videos/${videoID}`);
    return await uploadBytes(storageRef, file);
}
```

It works first time, video was added to my FireBase storage, and it's never worked again. No errors, no logs, etc..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the videoID unique or the same for every upload?